# An entire function such that $if(z)= \bar f(z)$ for all $z$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, maximum-principle

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $if(z)= \bar f(z)$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$. Show that $f$ is the constant function.

I didn't understand it but I took some notes which seem like gibberish to me now. Maybe someone could clarify:

- I had drawn a line on a graph that has an arg of $\pi/4$ then drew the conjugate of that so a line with arg of $-\pi/4$. Where did this come from?
- I had defined $f(z) = w$ and did $iw=\bar w$. Were supposed to solve(?) that and somehow end up with $w=$ $e^{-i\pi/4 + in\pi}$.

Can someone elaborate on these steps and clarify what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $\bar f$ are holomorphic, they are constant. Proof. If $f$ holomorphic then $\det f'(z_0) = \vert f'(z_0)\vert ^2 \geq 0$, where $f'(z_0)$ is a linear map from $\bf R^2$ to itself.

As the linear map $C: z\to \bar z$ has determinant $\det C=-1$, $\det (\bar f '(z_0)) \leq 0$. So if at some point $f'(z)\not = 0$ $\bar f$ is not holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

If $\overline f$ is *also* an analytic function then its components satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations in reverse. Together with the ordinary CR equations this puts all partial derivatives equal to 0.

Independently of these considerations, you can also argue that $(\overline f)^2=if\overline f=i|f|^2,$ which lies on the positive imaginary axis, so the image of $\overline f$ lies on the line through 0 defined by argument $\pi/4+k\pi.$

This implies that $\frac1{1+\overline f}$ is a bounded entire function so it, as well as $\overline f$ and $f$ itself, must be constant.

Comment: Please read the question friend.

Comment: @Cayde: This answer is actually good enough to answer the question, because $\bar{f}$ is entire if and only if $-i\bar{f}$ is entire, and $-i\bar{f} \equiv f$.

Comment: I'm not looking for a sufficient way to answer this. I want to learn what I missed from my teacher. I want to moreover understand the Max Modulus Principal. The title was changed (not by me) but it was about MMP.

Comment: I hope my adapted answer helps you understand the twisted explanation by your teacher.

Comment: There's no need for any of that. Where does the $k\pi$ come from and what can we conclude from having this argument?

Comment: Actually $k=0,1$ is enough. For the square of a number to lie on a given half line bounded by the origin, the number itself must lie on a line through the origin.

Comment: And we can conclude that this "entire" function has its image on a line, which is rather bizarre behaviour for an entire function. But we are not going to conclude that it is constant from purely algebraic considerations - the analyticity has to be used somewhere (which is why I proposed CR).

Comment: Would you advise Cauchy Riemann over MMP? To me C-R seems easier but I'm just thinking what if I have something that cant be solved via C-R manipulation.

Comment: I have nothing against the maximum modulus principle but I do not see where it occurs in your teacher's notes.